# How to print numbers divisible by 7

Tags: r

Is there any function that allows me to check if x is divisible by any number? I need to write a repeat loop with integers ranging from 1:100 and also using if function write all the numbers divisible by 7 from that range.
Here is what I got so far:

```
x <- 1
repeat {
    print(x)
    x = x+1
    if (x > 100) {
        break
    }
}
```

It only prints first part of what I need.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have to do all that. Use the modulo operator `%%` and the beauty of R's vectorization.

```
which(1:100 %% 7 == 0)
# [1]  7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 77 84 91 98
```

Or if you're playing code golf, make it even shorter ...

```
which(!1:100 %% 7)
# [1]  7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 77 84 91 98
```

Comment: @Kristofersen - It is negating the result of `1:100 %% 7`, so any zeros become TRUE (because logically they are FALSE), and FALSE otherwise

Comment: Crazy, I've never seen that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the range of number divisible by a `n` number:

```
val n = Array.range(2000,3200).filter((i: Int) => i%7==0)
    print(n.mkString(","))
```

If you want to find the range of number divisible by a `n` number and want to add some more conditions on it:

```
val n = Array.range(2000,3200).filter((i: Int) => i%7==0 && i%5!=0)
    print(n.mkString(","))
```

*Note*: If you use `List` in place of `Array` then the result also will be something like this: `List(23,456,67,889…n)`. But if you use `Array` you will get a normal comma-separated values or whichever separator you have used.